# Increment cell value of DataFrame using df.at[] += x not working

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, for-loop, auto-increment

I want to create a dataframe like this:

```
     Days      2014   2015   etc...
Sunday           46     44
Monday            5      1
Tuesday           3      0
Wednesday         2      0
Thursday          1      2
Friday            1      0
Saturday         36     12
```

From this:

```
     Days      2014 
Sunday            0     
Monday            0      
Tuesday           0      
Wednesday         0      
Thursday          0      
Friday            0      
Saturday          0
```

When I want to increment the value of a specific cell, it will give me this error:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Here is my code:

```
for y in unique_years:

    missing_days_df = pd.DataFrame({'Days': ['Sunday', 'Monday', 'Tuesday', 'Wednesday', 'Thursday', 'Friday',
                                             'Saturday']})

    missing_days_df[y] = "0"

    missing_days_df[y].astype(int)

    gold_days_year = pd.to_datetime(dates[dates.dt.year == y])

    normal_days_year = pd.date_range(start=gold_days_year[0], end=gold_days_year.iloc[-1], freq='D')

    missing_for_year = pd.to_datetime(normal_days_year[~normal_days_year.isin(gold_days_year)])

    week_days = pd.Series(missing_for_year.day_name())

    for x in week_days:

        k = missing_days_df[missing_days_df['Days'] == x].index.tolist()

        k = int(k[0])

        missing_days_df.at[k, y] += 1
```

I have tried converting the y column to int instead of string using this call:

```
missing_days_df[y].astype(int)
```

But nothing changes. I've looked at many similar questions on this site but none quite matches my specific problem.

Would anyone have a quick fix?

Comment: this line: `missing_days_df[y].astype(int)` creates a new `pd.Series` which is immediately discarded, and doesn't affect the dataframe at all (or the original series)

Comment: Thanks this helped me! I modified it to `missing_days_df[y] = missing_days_df[y].astype(int)` and it worked! It's incrementing now!